# rails generate migration add_index_to... does not put the actual index in the migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a users table via "rails generate model User name:string email:string ..."  the migration file was created as well.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to add an index to the email column "following the tutorial"  I've done this successfully the first time through using sqlite3. Second time through im using MySql (mysql2).  Again created the table fine with generate model..  When I run the following:

```
rails generate migration add_index_to_users_email
```

the process ends with no error message and creates the migration file as shown below, but there is no setting of any index..

```
class AddIndexToUsersEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

Im expecting to see  `add_index :users, :email, unique: true` in there ...  Anybody have any idea's..  searched other threads to no avail..  running rails 4, mysql 5.6 ruby 1.9.3   my schema that was created after initil db:migrate is:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131024161033) do

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.string   "mobile_phone"
    t.string   "mobile_phone_type"
    t.date     "birth_date"
    t.string   "user_type"
    t.string   "ss_num"
    t.boolean  "agree_to_terms"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 45):

via http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

> If you'd like to add an index on the new column, you can do that as
>   well:
>
> $ rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts
>   part_number:string:index

your generator

```
rails generate migration add_index_to_users_email
```

simply creates an empty migration file and did not describe a index

so this would be more appropriate...

```
rails generate migration AddIndexToUsers email:string:index
```

should give you

```
class AddIndexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :email
  end
end
```

---

### Nguyen You - EDIT

This command [Rails 5.2.3]

```
rails generate migration AddIndexToUsers email:string:index
```

actually will give you

```
class AddIndexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :users, :email, :string
    add_index :users, :email
  end
end
```

not only `add_index` but also `add_column` to the users table.

Comment: Yes that worked..  Perhaps when using mysql the syntax that you provided is key, but sqllite worked for my migration command, oh well, thanks for your help.

Comment: I am always getting add_column, though my column is already there in table.

Answer (score 15):

`rails generate migration AddIndexToUsers email:string:index`

if you already have column it just add index, like:

```
class AddIndexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :email
  end
end
```

if you create new column (you haven't got column in database yet), it returns:

```
class AddIndexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :user, :email, :string
    add_index :users, :email
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

From the http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/modeling-users#code-email_uniqueness_index.

The email uniqueness migration is not pre-defined, so we need to fill in its contents with this by ourself  " add_index :users, :email, unique: true " .

The result will be:

```
class AddIndexToUsersEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```